# upgrade 20.10 to 21.04 interrupted

Tags: upgrade, software-installation, spyder, 21.04

While upgrading from ubuntu 20.10 to ubuntu 21.04(hirsute), the upgrading failed in the middle of the process. I have forwarded the errors to the Hirsute team. Will, I received information on how to continue with the installation? I got the Hirsute 'logo' and appears that only works fine the programs based on python3.9 as for example IDLE3.9 for python. Spider worked fine with ubuntu 20.10. Now it does not.

Comment: This is a poorly worded question, and does not include needed detail. What exactly happened? What error messages did you see, if any? It is difficult to parse your sentences "I got the..." and "Spider worked...".

Comment: It seems that this crash was expected because a ready crash box was provided just to click it in order for the crash details to be sent to Ubuntu if I wanted. It appears that after this crash I was returned to the new windows (ubuntu 21.04) and from there I was able to download PyCharm, Visual Studio Code, and NetBeans without any problems. Spyder(python3.8) did not work on the new Python3.9.

Comment: I urge you to read: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 0):

You are likely to receive a personalized response soon ONLY if:

1. You are registered at Launchpad.net with your proper contact information.
2. You filed a proper bug report (not merely sending crash data).
3. The bug report is complete. A developer can reliably duplicate the problem in their test environment right now.
4. The bug report is prioritized as CRITICAL or HIGH.

Very few bugs meet this threshold.

Your issue looks unlikely to meet this threshold, since your question not provided a lot of the basic information necessary to reproduce the problem in a test environment. Legions of volunteer testers tried upgrading from 20.04. Some filed bug reports. The developers fixed many of the reported problems that they could reliably reproduce.

Advice: Backup your data, and clean-install Ubuntu 21.04

Comment: The upgrade collapsed almost at the end with a request to send the details of the crash directly to them (ubuntu) by clicking a bottom that appeared on a crash box after the crash happen. That is what I did. Ubuntu said, on the same crash box, that they will get in touch with me if Ubuntu finds it necessary. However, Ubuntu 21.04 seems to work fine. I have managed to download some applications without problems.

Comment: Well, then the developers almost certainly won't contact you.

Comment: The upgrade indeed caused some applications and packages to stop working. For example, I could not run Fenics programs on Spyder IDLE. I had to reset, manually the Python interpreter path, to /usr/bin/python3/ in the Spyder-Preference menu. That interpreter works fine for Spyder IDLE and Fenics packages call/imports.